# Setting default template language (add new item dialog) for visual studio community

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been using visual studio community for a long time and it was working fine. I prefer to use C# as my programming language but recently I found that whenever I try to add new item using

**Right click on item > Add > New Item**

I dialog appear that says to choose a template to work on. But here the default templates shown are of VB.Net. Many times accidentally I choose template of VB.NET instead of C# and later I come to know about that when I have to work for C# and I have recreate that file afresh for C#.

How it is possible that whenever I choose Add New Item, default templates of C# should be there to choose from instead of selecting the language from left pane and then choosing the template.

Comment: what is your current visual studio version, vs2017 or vs 2019? If your visual studio is vs2019, you can choose Add>New project>Choose **All Languages**>**C#**.  Like the pic   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmiGs.png

Comment: Its not about New Project but New Item. I already have been working on a project where default language is C# but when I add New Item like WebForm it show a dialog where I want to set the default language.